# Get module name for Child class that inherits a parent class for the current execution

Tags: python

In `ParentModule.py` module we have the following class:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        #Code that gets the module that inherits this class 
        pass
        
    def parentMethod(self):
        pass
```

In `childModule.py` module we have the following class:

```
class child(parent):
    def childMethod(self):
        pass
```

In `externalModule.py` module we import and create an instance of child class:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from childModule.py import child
    childInstance = child()
    childInstance.parentMethod()
```

Is there a way when `externalModule` is ran to get the module name for the `child` class, but the piece of code that does this to be in `parent` class constructor?

Comment: *"Code that gets the module that inherits this class"* - modules can't inherit...

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's possible; I've just never seen it done in practice, and it certainly doesn't occur here.

Comment: @chepner can you link to some source about that? Never heard of modules inheriting

Comment: `from types import ModuleType; class A(ModuleType): pass`. Of course, the *default* import mechanism doesn't provide a way to define a module subclass, but the machinery provided by `importlib` would let you provide your own import semantics.

Comment: (And yes, I'm just being extremely pedantic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) under "Custom classes", it says:

> Special attributes:... `__module__` is the module name in which the class was defined;

So you can get the module name with `type(self).__module__`.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__module__)
```

Comment: That's the class name, not the module name.

Comment: My bad, just fixed it.